# UIImage size is changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

currently I have a split and I want to split it into two different images.

I currently have it working, but it isn't getting the frame correctly.

```
// @property of UIImage
self.splitImage = [_displayLastPhoto image];
NSLog(@"Split image %f %f", self.splitImage.size.width, self.splitImage.size.height);
[self setViewShow:self.successfulMessage];
CGImageRef tmpImgRef = self.splitImage.CGImage;
CGImageRef leftImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.splitImage.size.width / 2.0, self.splitImage.size.height));

UIImage *leftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:leftImgRef];
NSLog(@"Left image %f %f", leftImage.size.width, leftImage.size.height);
CGImageRelease(leftImgRef);

CGImageRef rightImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(self.splitImage.size.width / 2.0, 0,  self.splitImage.size.width / 2.0, self.splitImage.size.height));
UIImage *rightImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:rightImgRef];
NSLog(@"Right image %f %f", rightImage.size.width, rightImage.size.height);
CGImageRelease(rightImgRef);
```

So right now the right side image + the left side image width should be equal to the `_displayLastPhot`'s width. But it isn't.

**Edit** I hardcoded the width and height to match up with `_displayLastPhoto` width and height and it matches. But the left and right images seemed very zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go about doing this:

- use UIImage size and not the frame of the diplaying UIImageView
- create the images sizes using bounds' not frame's width and height
- remove aspect fit or whatever scaling on UIImageView when doing some visual sanity checks. Scale after you verified your images are split correctly

good luck

Comment: I took your advice and tried to do this, but still doesn't work.